# Storing objects in an std::map

Tags: c++

I'd like to store objects of a class in an `std::map`. Here is a working example showing how I am doing it currenty

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class A
{
private:
  int a;
  std::string b;

public:
  A(int init_a, std::string init_b) : a(init_a), b(init_b){};  
  void output_a() {std::cout << a << "\n";}
};

int main()
{
  std::map<size_t, A> result_map;
  for (size_t iter = 0; iter < 10; ++iter)
  {
    A a(iter, "bb");
    result_map.insert(std::make_pair(iter, a));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have two question to this example:

1. Is this the professional C++-way to store objects in an `std::map` in the above case? Or should I create a pointer to an object of `A` and store that instead? I like the first (current) option as I don't have to worry about memory management myself by using `new` and `delete` - but most importantly I'd like to do things properly.
2. How would I go about calling a member function of, say, `result_map[0]`? I naively tried `result_map[0].output_a()`, but that gave me the error: `error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’`

Comment: You could use the syntax `result_map[iter] = a;`.

Comment: _"...but that gave me an error"_: always useful to include the error in your post.

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. "but that gave me an error." - what error? I get no errors when trying to do `result_map[key].function()`

Comment: ***error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’*** Class `A` has no default constructor but has one that requires 2 parameters.

Comment: @drescherjm Why is a default constructor necessary when trying to invoke a member function? The objects are already initialized

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no he could not, that would not compile

Comment: @BillyJean default constructor is necessary for `std::map::operator[]`, not to invoke member function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this the professional C++-way to store objects in an std::map in the above case?

It is fine, simpler code could be:

```
result_map.emplace(iter, A(iter, "bb") );
```

you should use whatever you find more readable. By the way calling integer counter `iter` is not a way to write a readable code.

> How would I go about calling a member function of, say, result_map[0]?

You better use `std::map::find`:

```
auto f = result_map.find( 0 );
if( f != result_map.end() ) f->output_a();
```

problem with `operator[]` in your case - it has to create and instance if object does not exist with that index but you do not have default ctor for `A`.

Answer (score 0):

1- **It depends:** If your class can be copied and you're not worried about performance issues with copying objects into the map, then that's a good way to do it. However, if say your class held **any** immutable data (`std::mutex` for example) you'd have to use a pointer, as the copy constructor c++ automatically generates would be ill formed, so it merely wouldn't be able to copy the class

2- `result_map.at(0).output_a()` or `result_map.at(0)->output_a()` if you're using a map of pointers